# Backus-Naur Form (BNF) Recursion

Tags: bnf

I'm having trouble on how to express something recursive in BNF. A 'term' in my case can be formed by a value, multiply and divide (shown in image), I came up with the following:

```
<term> ::= <value>
              | <value> “*”
              | <value> “/”
```

[image]

Comment: I think it should be `t := v | t * t | t / t`

Comment: That makes more sense, thanks for that.

Answer (score 5):

Recursive specification is a specification in which the non terminal appears recursively in the production rules. 
Take a look at following grammar which is a recursive specification that contains +, *, $(exponentiation) and  uses BNF notation:

```
 <exp>     := <exp> + <term> | <term>
 <term>    := <term> * <factor> | <factor>
 <factor>  := <factor> $ <primary> | <primary>
 <primary> := id
```

As you can see all non terminal which are in LHS of := are also in production (RHS) so it is called Recursive BNF notation.